# Powershell WPF Textbox into array

Tags: wpf, powershell, xaml

I have a WPF form that opens a textbox for user input, going for a line seperated list of PC names.  No matter how I try separating them the values all end coming back as a single item, a mutli-line item sure, but one item.  I can't get those to go into my array one line at a time.
Here's the XAML along with a few of the things I've tried through many attempts to get this into my array. Note that the textbox.lines doesn't seem to return anything though I read that's might work for my needs.

```
$inputXML = @"
<Window x:Name="Add_to_AD_Group" x:Class="Form.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MSIForm"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Add to AD for SCCM Deployment" Height="327.57" Width="283.937">
    <Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.511,0.499">
        <TextBox x:Name="MachinesList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="155" Margin="62,100,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="163" AcceptsReturn="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Enter Machine list below" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="62,73,0,0" Height="22" Width="163"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Select AD Group" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="62,10,0,0" Height="24" Width="163"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="ADGroupsList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="62,39,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="163" IsEditable="True"/>
        <Button x:Name="OK" Content="OK" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="46,268,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <Button x:Name="Cancel" Content="Cancel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="161,268,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" IsCancel="True"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
"@

$TempVar = $WPFMachinesList.Text
$TempVar = $TempVar.Trim()
# = $TempVar.Split([Environment]::NewLine)
#, [StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries
#foreach ($item in $TempVar) {$Machinearray += $item}
#$TempVar = ($TempVar -split '/r?/n').Trim()
Out-GridView -InputObject $TempVar -Title "WPF Machines List"
```

The out-GridView displays something like this:
[Out-Gridview test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcIP8.png)

Thanks for any help!

Update: I am trying to get a list of machines back from the Textbox to run through a set of command for each machine name, I have tried all kinds of string manipulation and cannot get the list as individual items it comes back as a single item from the textbox. For my XAML, I use VS to get this  xaml code and powershell around it to launch it and modify it. E.g. I have powershell getting a list of groups from an OU, and  use that to populate the combobox, then the list of machines would be added to the selected group, so there is no more to the xaml code itself than this.  Here's the full xaml function if that helps determine what I'm doing wrong.

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("presentationframework")

Function Get-MachineList {

$inputXML = @"
<Window x:Name="Add_to_AD_for_SCCM_Deployment" x:Class="Form.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MSIForm"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Add to AD for SCCM Deployment" Height="327.57" Width="283.937">
    <Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.511,0.499">
        <TextBox x:Name="MachinesList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="155" Margin="62,100,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="163" AcceptsReturn="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Enter Machine list below" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="62,73,0,0" Height="22" Width="163"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Select AD Group" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="62,10,0,0" Height="24" Width="163"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="ADGroupsList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="62,39,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="163" IsEditable="True"/>
        <Button x:Name="OK" Content="OK" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="46,268,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <Button x:Name="Cancel" Content="Cancel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="161,268,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" IsCancel="True"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
"@
$inputXML = $inputXML -replace 'mc:Ignorable="d"','' -replace "x:N",'N' -replace "x:C", "C" -replace '^<Win.*', '<Window' 


[xml]$XAML = $inputXML
#Read XAML

    $reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml) 
    try{$Form=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($reader)}
    catch{Write-Host "Unable to load Windows.Markup.XamlReader. Double-check syntax and ensure .net is installed."
    Write-Host $_.Exception.Message;exit}

#===========================================================================
# Load XAML Objects In PowerShell
#===========================================================================

$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | %{Set-Variable -Name "WPF$($_.Name)" -Value $Form.FindName($_.Name)}


Function Get-FormVariables{
    if ($global:ReadmeDisplay -ne $true){Write-host "If you need to reference this display again, run Get-FormVariables" -ForegroundColor Yellow;$global:ReadmeDisplay=$true}
    write-host "Found the following interactable elements from our form" -ForegroundColor Cyan
    get-variable WPF*
}

Get-FormVariables{
}

#===========================================================================
# Actually make the objects work
#===========================================================================
$Script:GroupsList = Get-ADObject -Filter 'ObjectClass -eq "group"' -SearchBase "OU=Applications,OU=Groups,OU=AAM-Enterprise,DC=AAM,DC=NET" -Credential $creds | sort

foreach ($group in $GroupsList) {$WPFADGroupsList.Items.Add($group.Name)}

    $WPFOK.Add_Click{
        $TempVar = ($WPFMachinesList.Text).Trim()
        #$TempVar = @(($TempVar.Trim()) -split "`r`n,")
        # = $TempVar.Split([Environment]::NewLine)
        #, [StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries
        #foreach ($item in $TempVar) {$Machinearray += $item}
        Out-GridView -InputObject $TempVar -Title "WPF Machines List"
        #foreach ($machine in $TempVar) {
            #$line = $line | Out-String
            #$MachineArray = @()
            #$MachineArray += $($line)}
            #VerifySCCMClient $machine
            #Get-SelectedGroup
        #}
    }
    $Form.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") 
        {
            $Error.Clear()
            $ADSCCMForm.Close()
        }
    }
    )
#Sample entry of how to add data to a field
#$vmpicklistView.items.Add([pscustomobject]@{'VMName'=($_).Name;Status=$_.Status;Other="Yes"})

#===========================================================================
# Shows the form
#===========================================================================
Write-Host "To show the form, run the following" -ForegroundColor Cyan
$Form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
}

Get-MachineList
```

Comment: You say you are using your own custom WPF, but you show you are using the default PowerShell Out-Gridview cmdlet. You cannot apply WPF/XAML to this cmdlets UI. In your grid, you have no row or column definitions in your XAML. Please show more of your firm code and what your results look like for your firm, VS then cmdlet.

Comment: It should just be String manipulation if its a TextBox.... from your image however, it doesn't look like a TextBox.... more like a list.

Comment: I found the issue, partially idiot (PEBKAC) mistakes and also a difference in how Out-Gridview handles variables passed to it from either pipline ($variable | Out-Gridview) works but {Out-Gridview -Inputobject $variable) is weird.

Answer (score 0):

You had everything needed:

1. a trimed string
2. a split for `[environment]::NewLine`
3. `[System.StringSplitOptions]"RemoveEmptyEntries"` to get rid of empty lines.

Put it together and the line looks like this:

```
$TempVar = ($WPFMachinesList.Text.Trim()).split([environment]::NewLine,[System.StringSplitOptions]"RemoveEmptyEntries")
```

This will create an array from the lines you entered in the textbox.